# How do I make inputted letters as big letters using asterisk?

Tags: python, letter

For example i inputted "ABC"

The output should be:

```
*** **  ***
* * * * *
*** **  *
* * * * *
* * **  ***
```

I only tried the letter A but it results an error.
Can someone help me do it in plain python without any modules

```
text = input("Enter my text: ").split()

A = [3, [1,0,1], 3, [1,0,1], [1,0,1]]

for i in range(text+1):
    if text[i] == 'A':
        print("*" * A[i])
```

Comment: Why not pre-render the alphabet, and then just look up the strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
a = {
    "a": [
        "***",
        "* *",
        "***",
        "* *",
        "* *",
    ],
    "b": [
        "** ",
        "* *",
        "** ",
        "* *",
        "** ",
    ]
}

string = "abab"

data = [a[char] for char in string]

# 5 because the "big letters" have 5 rows
for i in range(5):
    row = " ".join(d[i] for d in data)
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

That representation seems inconsistent, if you wanted to use a matrix to represent which elements are asterisks I'd suggest

```
A = [[1,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,0,1]]
```

Then you can loop over each row and print out either an asterisk or whitespace as appropriate

```
for row in A:
    print(''.join('*' if s == 1 else ' ' for s in row))

***
* *
***
* *
* *
```